# Why does it create dangling image?

Tags: docker

I have Dockerfile, that looks as the following:

```
FROM openjdk:8 as stage0
WORKDIR /opt/docker
COPY opt /opt
USER root
RUN ["chmod", "-R", "u=rX,g=rX", "/opt/docker"]
RUN ["chmod", "u+x,g+x", "/opt/docker/bin/sapmock"]

FROM openjdk:8
USER root
RUN id -u demiourgos728 2> /dev/null || (( getent group 0 || groupadd -g 0 root ) && useradd --system --create-home --uid 1001 --gid 0 demiourgos728 )
WORKDIR /opt/docker
COPY --from=stage0 --chown=demiourgos728:root /opt/docker /opt/docker
EXPOSE 8080
USER 1001:0
ENTRYPOINT ["/opt/docker/bin/sapmock"]
CMD []
```

Then I've create an image as the following:

```
docker build -t sapmock .
Sending build context to Docker daemon  38.83MB
Step 1/15 : FROM openjdk:8 as stage0
8: Pulling from library/openjdk
```

The build was successful. When I list the created images, it shows:

```
 docker images
REPOSITORY          TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED              SIZE
sapmock             latest              b0c10315185f        About a minute ago   664MB
<none>              <none>              c9210e522d87        About a minute ago   703MB
openjdk             8                   bec43387959a        2 weeks ago          625MB
```

What is the `<none>` images, why it was created?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The two `FROM` lines build two images as part of a multi-stage build, but you only tag one of them at the end. The other image remains for your build cache, allowing future builds to run faster and reuse the layers from previous builds.

Comment: Awesome answer. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

When you create a new docker image, if it has the same name as an existing docker image, the old one doesn't get deleted and instead gets turned into a "dangling image", with the name and tag `<none>`

You can remove dangling images with `docker images -f dangling=true`

Comment: But, why does it try to create twice?

Comment: Because you retrieve openjdk:8 twice in your build. This is how docker works with multi-stage builds. https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/34151